# Dart. Child class and constructor initializer list

Tags: dart

I play with Dart (leaf through Tour of the Dart Language) and I found that I can't use initializer list on child classes. Why?

```dart
main() {
  var rbt = new Robot.fromJson({'x':21, 'y':21});
}

class Human {

}

class Robot extends Human {
  int x;
  int y;
  Robot.fromJSON(Map map) : x = map['x'], y = map['y'] {
    print('Robot location is $x, $y');
  }
}
```

Causes an error:

```
Exception: No constructor 'Robot.fromJson' declared in class 'Robot'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'Robot.fromJson'
Receiver: Type: class 'Robot'
Arguments: [Instance of '_LinkedHashMap']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart is case-sensitive

`fromJSON` vs `fromJson`

Comment: Oh! Thanks I need be more careful or maybe I need a break..))